# Axios PATCH request is not ajax

Tags: javascript, php

I am doing a PATCH request. The request goes through and returns as it should but it is not ajax.

I added an if statement to check this.
How is it possible to use Axios and it is not ajax? I thought that Axios is a library that wraps around ajax.

Any tips?

(Tried with GET or POST, same result. Not Ajax)

in HTML

```html
<button data-id="1">button</button>
```

in Javascript file

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    let id = button.getAttribute('data-id');
    patchRequest(id);
});
const patchRequest = async (id) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.patch(`/action/${id}`);
        return response.data.success;
    } catch (err) {
        return console.log(err.response.data);
    }
};
```

inside the Controller

```php
public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        // do something and then respond
        if($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json(['success' => $result], 201);
        } else {
            return 'not ajax';
        }
    }
```

in web.php (Routes file)

```php
Route::patch('action/{id}', SomeController::class);
```

**UPDATE**

User @T.J.Crowder helped with his comment.

What solved my problem was adding this

```js
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Comment: All that probably means is that that `ajax` method's check doesn't recognize the request as "ajax." For instance, it might be checking the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header, which `axios` probably doesn't set for you. (You can set it yourself, though.)

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder , setting the header solved it.

Comment: Oh, great! I've converted that comment to an answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that the `ajax` method is looking for the header often used on ajax requests, `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`. `axios` probably doesn't set that header, but you can do it manually if you like.